# Basic gates sets

Tags: quantum-gate, universal-gates

There are several basic gate sets allowing to construct any gate on a quantum gate-based computer, e.g.:

- $H$, $T$, $CNOT$ (sometimes enriched to $H$, $T$, $S$, $X$, $CNOT$),
- rotations $Rx$, $Ry$ and $Rz$ and $CNOT,$
- Toffoli gate + $H,$
- Fredkin gate + $H.$

I am wondering whether there are any other universal sets usually used in quantum computation. What are advantages and drawbacks of these sets?

Comment: The native gate set for IBM hardware is $CX, ID, RZ, SX, X$

Comment: Note that $W = \frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @KAJ226: Thanks for you input. What do you mean by $SX$? Is it a tranpose conjugate to $S$?

Comment: @MarkS: Thanks, it is helpful.

Comment: No problem. It is the $\sqrt{X}$. https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.SXGate.html

Comment: Native gate set used by IonQ comprised of single qubit rotations, rotations $Rx$, $Ry$, and $XX$ 
 - Mølmer-Sørenson - two qubit gate.

Comment: @MarkS: Thanks for suggestion, I edited the question. I plan after a few days to make a summary of comments in answer (of course with acknowledgement of the answerers).

Comment: Would it be possible to delete comment to this question as I compiled their content to my own answer (with acknowledgement of answerers)?

Comment: Criteria for universality of quantum gates can be found inhttps://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.105.052602 and arxiv version https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.03862 see also https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.00547 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05780

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Community Wiki**

In Google's quantum computational supremacy experiment with their Sycamore transmon processor, they used single-qubit gates from $\{\sqrt{X},\sqrt{Y},\sqrt{W}\},$ with $W=\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Additionally for their two-qubit gates, they used something close to an $\mathsf{iSWAP}$ gate - something like a $\mathsf{SWAP}$ gate that adds a $i$ phase only to the $\vert11\rangle$ basis.

They say that supremacy experiments also like to use $\mathsf{CZ}$ gates, but one of the reasons they hint at these specific gates, in addition to being implementable on their devices, was that these gates appeared to maximize entanglement in a manner that made classical simulation more difficult.

(As an aside, classically we like to build most CMOS logic with $\mathsf{NAND}$ gates, although $\mathsf{NOR}$ gates also generate the set of Boolean functions.  There are engineering reasons and also historical reasons why, as hinted at in [this](https://www.quora.com/NAND-and-NOR-are-both-universal-gates-Why-is-NAND-preferred-over-NOR-gate-in-most-applications#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20cells%20are%20designed,comparable%20rise%20and%20fall%20time.&text=NAND%20gate%20has%20better%20ratio,gate%20is%20preferred%20over%20NOR.) Quora question).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of other basic gate sets based on comments to my question (*I included a name of a comment author to brackets*):

- The native gate set for IBM hardware is $CNOT$, $ID$, $Rz$, $X$ and $\sqrt{X}$ (by *KAJ226*)
- Google Sycamore gates: $\sqrt{X}$, $\sqrt{Y}$ and $\sqrt{W}$, where $W = (X + Y)/\sqrt{2}$ and gate similar to $iSWAP$ (described [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/understanding-googles-quantum-supremacy-using-a-programmable-superconducting-p) and [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8341/understanding-googles-quantum-supremacy-using-a-programmable-superconducting-p)) (by *Mark S*)
- Native gate set used by IonQ comprised of single qubit rotations $Rx$, $Ry$, and $XX$ which is [Mølmer-Sørenson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8lmer%E2%80%93S%C3%B8rensen_gate) two qubit gate (by *Egretta.Thula*)

Comment: I’d also add H/Toffoli if only for some nice theoretical reasons- namely, that set never introduces a complex phase if acting only on $|000\cdots 0\rangle$.

Comment: @Mark S: See my original question where I mentioned this set.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{X}$, $\sqrt{W}$ and the fSim gate (i.e. the iSWAP-like gate) are sufficient for universality, i.e. we don't actually need $\sqrt{Y}$. See VII F 2 on page $30$ in [the supplement](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11333) to the QS paper.