# Can Google Sycamore's benchmark for quantum supremacy be simulated on Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, google-sycamore

In 2019, Google claimed that they have achieved quantum supremacy/advantage with their 53 qubit quantum processor Sycamore. The paper is [here](https://doi.org/10.1038%2Fs41586-019-1666-5). But I have not even been able to find what their algorithm is called. I know that is just a sampling problem. How would I go to create a similar sampling for a smaller circuit (say 5 qubits) using Qiskit?

I have checked this good 3-part series of questions [Understanding Google's “Quantum supremacy using a programmable superconducting processor” (Part 1): choice of gate set](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/understanding-googles-quantum-supremacy-using-a-programmable-superconducting-p). Yet I am still unable to understand from where to start. Does Qiskit have predetermined functions for this purpose? Especially on how would I go to confirm it out later? My key issue here is that I do not know the name of the algorithm so I only have Google experiment related sources.

I am not concerned with the issue that they may have achieved quantum supremacy or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the benchmarking method used in this paper is called cross entropy benchmarking (XEB). An example circuit implementation for a 5 qubit XEB sequence is shown in fig. 3 of the paper.

For further info, I recommend looking at the supplementary information (SI) of this paper, particularly fig. S15. Another source of info for 2 qubit XEB and the cross entropy calculation for a small number of qubits can be found in section D of the SI here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.08343.pdf

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! What’s SI?

Comment: SI = supplementary info

Comment: There's also a few implementations of XEB as Cirq tutorials, see here for example: https://quantumai.google/cirq/qcvv/isolated_xeb

Comment: @forky40 yeah I noticed that once I knew it is called XEB, but I was looking for Qiskit resource.