# What is a gate-level circuit used in the 2022 Jafferis et al. experiment on Sycamore?

Tags: quantum-circuit, experimental-realization, google-sycamore

A recently published [Nature paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-05424-3) of Jafferis *et al.* describes an experiment with a handful of qubits performed on Google's Sycamore processor to explore the [SYK model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachdev%E2%80%93Ye%E2%80%93Kitaev_model) in the context of AdS/CFT and quantum gravity, and states that the experiment "represents a step towards a program for studying quantum gravity in the laboratory".

The figures in the Nature article appear to present a high-level summary of the experiment but not at the level of gates acting on the particular topology of Sycamore.  Figure 1c of Jafferis *et al.* appears to provide a standard wormhole-inspired teleportation circuit diagram, with time advancing upwards.

---

Figure 1 in an earlier counterpart [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.14081) of Shapoval *et al.*, as below, also provides a high-level summary of a wormhole-inspired teleportation protocol - this appears to be almost the same as in Figure 1c of Jafferis *et al.* with time advancing to the right.

[image: Figure 1 of Shapoval et al.]

In step 0, the Left and Right qubits are created as Bell pairs and correspond to the mouths of a wormhole.  In step 1, the Left black hole scrambles and evolves backwards in time until the target qubit $|\psi\rangle$ is introduced in step 2 while then evolving forward in time in step 3; in step 4 the wormhole gets injected with a negative-energy Hamiltonian $V$; while in step 5, by time-evolving the Right black hole the qubit $|\psi\rangle$ is teleported.

Additionally, Figure 4 in Shapoval *et al.* gets into the weeds of individual gates, and how they might be implemented on IBM's transmon devices and/or Quantinuum's trapped ion devices.

---

We know that the native 2-qubit gates used in earlier Sycamore experiments are related to **iSWAP** gates.  The Jafferis *et al.* experiment reportedly was done on a 72-qubit version of Sycamore but only uses nine of these qubits and apparently involves several hundred 1- and 2-qubit gates.

> What was the particular circuit used in this experiment, preferably at the level provided by the other [Sycamore experiments](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8342/understanding-googles-quantum-supremacy-using-a-programmable-superconducting-p) or at the level of Shapoval *et al.*'s proposal?

For example, were the other qubits on Sycamore **Id**ling, or were they doing any other supportive ancillary work (such as **SWAP**ping info and out)? Did the circuit use these **iSWAP** gates, or something more subtle?  How deep was the circuit?  Apparently an important aspect of the experiment involved classical machine-learning to simplify and sparsify the Hamiltonian - did this machine learning characterize other qubits not used in the circuit, to know which ones not to use?

Comment: If it helps, I can add that they use 164 CZ gates and 295 single-qubit gates.  The sublattice they use is almost a 3x3 square lattice, but the bottom-right qubit is actually one unit to the right of the middle-right qubit -- I believe these are all the qubits used.  Also, since they are simulating fermions they would need to use fswaps, not normal swaps.  I don't see any number for total circuit depth but they say that N=10 SYK model is "prohibitively deep", so they sparsify it to a N=7 model.

Comment: @chrysaor4 that does help!  Was this in the paper itself?

Comment: yep I quickly checked the paper and supplement

Comment: The paper can be accessed from [this link](https://t.co/qx1pVDywLA). Also, rather than duplicate the circuit, what does it take to simulate the 7 fermion "learned" hamiltonian in the paper: $H_{L,R}=-0.36\psi^1\psi^2\psi^4\psi^5+0.19\psi^1\psi^3\psi^4\psi^7-0.71\psi^1\psi^3\psi^5\psi^6+0.22\psi^2\psi^3\psi^4\psi^6+0.49\psi^2\psi^3\psi^5\psi^7?$

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you actually can contact the authors through their email listed on the paper and ask this question. If you want them to respond, I suggest you write no more than two sentences and be very clear in your writing

Comment: Reference 9 in the Nature paper is Gao and Jafferis 2021. It also talks about the gates at some level of detail: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.07416